# OpenXML with mailmerge fields in a Word DOCX file - full example

Tags: sql-server-2005, openxml, mailmerge, word-2007

I know there are heaps and heaps of threads out there on recommending and using OpenXML to manipulate a Word 2007 (docx) document.

But none I could find, have a practical example (full solution in zip) that I am able to try out and demonstrate to learn quickly how to use OpenXML.
What I am after is a way to open a Word 2007 document template with several mailmerge fields, populate those fields from a dataset (SQL Server 2005) and save the template as a Word document ready to email.

- UPDATE: We are using Visual Studio 2005 with .Net 2. Is that going to be a problem? Could we have .Net 3 installed but still use VS2005? Porting to VS2010 is in the cards for us, but not right now. We need a solution to this problem before we go upgrading to 2010.

And please do not recommend 3rd party products as we have to look for a free workable solution.

Much appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly the same problem I have http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/17/t/5354.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [an example](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j.NET/blob/master/docx4j.NET/src/samples/c%23/Docx4NET/MailMergeField.cs).

It uses docx4j.NET - which is open source and which you can [get from Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/3.0.1) - not Microsoft's Open XML SDK.

Comment: That link is dead. I think you mean this one? https://github.com/plutext/docx4j.NET/tree/master/docx4j.NET/src/samples/c%23/Docx4NET

Comment: Again thanks but as I said above, docx4j.NET is not going to work for us as we only have VS2005